# Is there any way I could read Web Push notifications sent from a website to Chrome from Python?

Tags: python, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, web-push

There's a website I use that sends me notifications using Web Push. So I'm receiving these notifications just fine on macOS via Chrome. I'd like to forward these notifications to an iOS device via Pushbullet but the website doesn't provide a way to do so.

So I solved it right now by reading macOS' notifications sqlite database and sending the ones I want to Pushbullet's API and I receive them on my phone. I was wondering if there's any better way.

I tried opening the Chrome DevTools and recording Background Services → Push Messaging and I can see a log of notifications in json. How can I read those notifications?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>This may not be the answer that you're looking for, but have you considered installing Google Chrome on your smartphone and registering that device with the website for push notifications?</strike> As pointed out in the comment, Chrome on iOS does not support Web Push.

Another suggestion: while creating the push subscription the website also registers a service worker. This service worker responds to incoming push events. If you open Chrome DevTools, go to to the *Sources* tab, and open the service worker, you can add whatever code you want. I'm not sure if this change persists when you exit Chrome though.

[image: Modified service-worker.js]
[image: Showing the modification is executed]

Comment: Unfortunately Chrome on iOS doesn't have Web Push notifications. I think no browser on iOS has Web Push as they all rely on Safari/WebKit.

Comment: I wasn't aware of this, but you're right indeed. I've updated my answer with another solution, which involves modifying the service worker after it gets registered.

Comment: Thank you, that indeed does work and I can make it persist by using Chrome DevTools' Local Overrides feature, it even works in the background. Maybe you should also state that in your answer for future readers. Thanks again!

Comment: Actually it doesn't persist… you have to keep a Chrome tab open with DevTools open. Still works tho! Maybe there's a way to make it persist but for the scope of the question this is enough.